# Radio button for single selection in sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

When using multi selection in a sap.ui.table.Table, there are checkboxes displayed on the left or right side, which indicate the selected row. But when using single selection, this selection column, where in this case radio buttons should be displayed, is simply empty and only the complete row is highlighted when selected. Is there a simple way to also add radio buttons or any other kind of highlighting like an "X" to the additional column, which is empty?

[image: See image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is done to mimic an ALV grid in the SAP GUI.

If changing the control is an option then `sap.m.Table` has what you want (`mode="SingleSelectLeft"`). See the example [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.List/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelection).

If you want to stick with `sap.ui.table.Table` you probably have to build your own indicator (and remove the empty column at the beginning with `selectionBehavior="RowOnly"`). If already part of your model you can bind a `selected` property to your indicator. Or you could write a formatter that compares the current ID with the ID of the selected row of the table. Guess this can be done in a few minutes.

If this is about usability maybe it already helps if you change the `selectionBehavior` to `Row` (row will be selected when you click anywhere in that row). The default is `RowSelector` (row will be selected only when you click the empty column at the beginning of the row).